# How to select table view in javafx from controller?

Tags: javafx

When I select a row in tableview, I need take the value of a given column. I'm doing this way, but is returning a ObjectList value and not the Column value

```
tableviewgetSelectionModel().getSelectedItem()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you like to get the exact value of the column then you need to first cast the Object to the specific Generic Class then get the value of them.

See the link

https://forums.oracle.com/thread/2309693